# Ruby Beginner SQLCache is stale

Tags: ruby, caching, model

I am new to ruby and trying to work on the an application that uses caching. I have a code that actually wait for an database update and keep polling until it finds specific value.

The problem is I am getting a stale value from model is there any way to force the RVM to take it from db

```
while !(["success","error"].include? request.status)
      request = (Model.find_by_request_id req_id)
      puts(request.inspect)
      sleep 1
    end
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active waiting in a process is BAD!

Active waiting for some data in a database is VERY BAD!

you should consider using a message queue between your processes.

Have a look at http://gregmoreno.ca/using-rabbitmq-and-amqp-with-ruby/